# Sum up numbers and text numbers per row in a range

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have the following sheet.

```
H      I      J      K     ...     BD 
2,3    4      2,4,7        ...     1  
3,7                  10    ...     8,13
```

The cell ‘H’ has 2,3 as text but cell ’I’ has the number 4, cell ‘J’ has the 2,4,7 as text and cell ‘BD’ has 1 as a number. All the cells that have 2 or more numbers as text are separated by commas
I want to sum all numbers and non-numbers to one single row using array-formula.
The result must be

```
BE 
16 
41
```

The range is between H2:BD with H1:BD1 for the headers 
I have used this code:

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A1:A)=1;"BottleQty";if(len(A1:A)>0;
 SUBSTITUTE(transpose(query(transpose(H1:BD);;COLUMNS(H2:BD)));",";"");iferror(1/0))))
```

but the result is

```
BE 
2 3   4    2 4 7     1 
3 7              10  8 13
```

Any help ??
Thanks in advance

Comment: also how did you calculate 16? (instead of 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D),,99^99)))), 
      MMULT(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D),,99^99)), ", ")*1, 0), ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
    COLUMNS(IFERROR(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A2:D),,99^99)), ", ")*1, 0))))^0), ))
```

[image]